# How to Call an Action from a View and return its result?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, view, controller, action

I have defined an action on my controller which accepts an integer and returns a string value:

```
 public string SqlQuery(int listItemId)
        {
            return _sqlListSharePointList.GetSqlQueryFromCache(listItemId);
        }
```

How could I call this action from my view? also what other options do I have apart from AJAX?

I tried the below but didn't work:

```
$.get('/SqlReportList/SqlQuery', 1, function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
```

the "SqlReportList" is the name of my controller.

I also tried the below code:

$.get('/SqlReportList/SqlQuery/1', function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });

But it threw an exception on production that the listItemId is null.

Should I decorate my Action differently?

I also tried accessing it via fully qualified name but same error:

http://localhost:4574/SqlReportList/SqlQuery/1

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use ajax (which is recommended) then only way to call the method is thru page refresh, only that way you are hitting your server side (controller) again from the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.get('/SqlReportList/SqlQuery', { "listItemId": listItemId }, function (data) {
         $('#tbSqlQuery').text(data); }
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the parameter known at the time of rendering the surrounding page?

If so (and I've understood your question correctly) then you can use Html.RenderAction. See http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

If not, then you can only really use AJAX or a full page reload. For getting the URL right for AJAX, you should be able to use Url.Action with some placeholder value.

The T4MVC project offers strongly-typed support for various things including action URLs, even supporting explicit placeholders for Javascript code. See section 2.2.2 of http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/documentation